# Как оформить список по БЭМу

Tags: html, css, бэм

```
 <nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">О Нас</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
    <ul class="SubMenu">
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#">Вакансии</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Нововти</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Соглашение</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Как правильно оформить классы по БЭМу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="nav__list">
    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">О Нас</a></li>
    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Услуги</a></li>
    
    <ul class="nav__submenu">
      <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Ссылка 1</a></li>
      <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Ссылка 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Вакансии</a></li>
    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Новости</a></li>
    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Соглашение</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```